# How to add participants attributes fields with Limesurvey API?

Tags: api, limesurvey

I would like to reproduce the whole survey creation process in Limesurvey with API.

I try to add several attributes fields (like you do in the "Manage attributes" menu).

I already tried to use `set_survey_properties` with the `attributedescriptions` element, but without success.

Is it possible to do this with the API ?

Comment: I started my process with the add_survey API call. If it's not possible to do this operation, I will consider using the import_survey instead, tuning a LSS file before importation.